# Error when inserting data from a user input form into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, insert

I am new to python and I have written a simple python3 code that creates a form, links to a MySQL database table and then I would like the user to be able to insert data into the table. However, when data is entered into the form I get this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s), (f_name, l_name, address, pc, age, salary)' at
> line 1

I think the problem is the dictionary syntax? Unfortunately, I can't work it out. Any help welcome.

My code is

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector


root = Tk()
root.title("Adress")
root.geometry("500x500")

#create a database or connect to one
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="", port=5306,
                    user="",
                    passwd="",
                    database="",
                    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
                    )

#create submit Function for database
def submit():

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="", port=5306,
                    user="",
                    passwd="",
                    database="",
                    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
                    )

        cursor = conn.cursor()

#insert into table with placeholders in values
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO address (f_name, l_name, address, pc, age, salary) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s), (f_name, l_name, address, pc, age, salary)",
            {"f_name": "f_name.get()",
            "l_name": "l_name.get()",
            "address": "address.get()",
             "pc": "pc.get()",
            "age": "age.get()",
            "salary": "salary.get()"
            })

        conn.commit()
        print("Record inserted successfully into table")
        conn.close()

#clear the txt boxes

        f_name.delete(0, END)
        l_name.delete(0, END)
        address.delete(0, END)
        pc.delete(0, END)
        age.delete(0, END)
        salary.delete(0, END)

#create text boxes
f_name = Entry(root, width=30)
f_name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)
l_name = Entry(root, width=30)
l_name.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)
address = Entry(root, width=30)
address.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20)
pc = Entry(root, width=30)
pc.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)
age = Entry(root, width=30)
age.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20)
salary = Entry(root, width=30)
salary.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20)

#create textbox labels
f_name_label = Label(root, text="First Name: ")
f_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
l_name_label = Label(root, text="Last Name: ")
l_name_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)
address_label = Label(root, text="Address")
address_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20)
pc_label = Label(root, text="Post Code:")
pc_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)
age_label = Label(root, text="Age: ")
age_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20)
salary_label = Label(root, text="Salary")
salary_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)

#create & submit button
submit_btn = Button(root, text="Add to database",command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)


conn.commit()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The second column list, after the `values` clause is wrong. Remove it and you should be OK:

```sql
INSERT INTO address (f_name, l_name, address, pc, age, salary)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I now get a different error:  mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1